# How do I make the user edit/update the .py file in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django Project, and I want the User to be able to add the code in the `.py` file. Well, I have `.py` file that contains some code, and in the mid of code I have some lines of code that specify some rules for **Fuzzy Logic Algorithm**, such as below:

```
 ...
rule1 = scikit-fuzzy.control.Rule(input1["bad"] & input2["bad"] & input3["bad"] & input4["bad"] & input5["average"], output["poor"])
 ...
```

So, I have total `243` lines of codes (in other words rules) like the above centered between some code (that is above it and below it there some other code). Now, I want Admin to be able to edit and update these lines of codes in a way that, using Forms I will take the inputs from the Admin (such as: 'good', 'bad', 'average', 'bad', 'good', 'poor', and I want the system to create a new line of code taking these strings as inputs.

If admin enters: `'good', 'bad', 'average', 'bad', 'good', 'poor'`, I want the `.py` to have a new line after the `243r` line which should be like this:

```
rule243 = #
rule244 = scikit-fuzzy.control.Rule(input1["good"] & input2["bad"] & input3["average"] & input4["bad"] & input5["good"], output["poor"]
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Why just do not keep the logic rules in the database?

Comment: Is that possible? Actually I have to use those rules next in the calculation function of Fuzzy Logic Algorithm.

Comment: Also in Database, the rules will be stored as strings, not the line of code.

Comment: You can store the data as you want, but still, it is possible to move the rules to the database, and make it more dynamic

Comment: Can a line of code (not string strung between quotes or double quotes) be stored in database? For instance, can we store `a = 2 + 4` in database?

Comment: You can store this as an expression and then parse it.

Comment: My advice is to not allow users to change the code, it can make things more complicated.

Comment: Feel free to checkout the solution I presented underneath

Answer (score 0):

Actually this should be doable, I've a solution in mind, Let's implement it

#### Take caution

- This requires HIGH verification and because this is python code, You don't want to give the admin all the rights to execute *ANY* python code from the admin page. If the admin details gets hijacked, You're @#!$#ED.

Let's analyze the problem into smaller problems.

#### Big point

- We want to execute code from admin page

#### Smaller points

- We need to put multiple rules, and they are uncountable, A perfect job for a database model
- We will think of the code as `Rule` object. we will think of the dictionary key as a `RuleKey` object. we will think of `input` or `output` as `RuleType`
- In your case, `input1['good']` is the same as RuleTypeX[RuleKey] where x is an Integer starting from 1.
- We will think of the `RuleKey` as many-to-many relation with the `Rule`, The Rule can has many `RuleKey` objects and those `RuleKey` objects can exist in different `Rule` objects.

**THING TO CONSIDER**

- Verification is very important, **YOU DON'T WANT SOMEONE PASSING `eval()` IN YOUR CODE AND EXECUTE WHATEVER HE WANTS.**

I've created this *REGEXP* to match your code

```
scikit-fuzzy\.control\.Rule\(\s?((input[0-9]+\[("|')(poor|good|average|bad|whatever)("|')\])\s?&?\s?)+,?\s?(output[0-9]*\[("|')(poor|good|average|bad|whatever)("|')\])+\s?\)
```

Took a lot of time lol, Tested on [Regexr](https://regexr.com/), This matches your code well, paste your code there and test to see, feel free to improve it, this is not the main focus here.

```
class RuleKey(models.Model):
    class TYPES(models.IntegerChoices):
        INPUT = 0
        OUTPUT = 1

    content = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES.choices)  # choices are of type Integer, the field must also be Integer

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

`content` will contain any of `['poor', 'good', 'whatever']` and type will be 0 for `Input` and 1 for `Output` and *I MEANT TO TYPE IT CAPITALIZED* because we need to solve the caps problem too.

We have a function to check if the final code is valid before evaluating it.

```
def valid_python_code(code):
    if re.match(valid_code_pattern, code):
        return True

    return False
```

Don't use the stupid `RegexValidator` that django provides, It raises an Exception if it didn't match but IT RETURNS NONE IF IT MATCHES, makes no sense for me, or use it, whatever.

> When we run code, We're 'executing' it and this is the formal word for running code.

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    keys = models.ManyToManyField('RuleKey', related_name='rules')
    wasExecutedBefore = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # ran before or no

    def execute(self):
        if self.wasExecutedBefore:
            return None

        input_keys = self.keys.filter(type=0)
        output_keys = self.keys.filter(type=1)

        """
        Can't use f-strings as we're evaluating genexps here, note the key.type, In a production environment
        This should be RuleKey.TYPES.INPUT or RuleKey.TYPES.OUTPUT, just swap the places of the classes, I'm lazy to do that
        """
        code = "scikit-fuzzy.control.Rule({inputs}, {outputs})".format(
            inputs=''.join(
                f"{key.get_type_display().lower()}{i + 1}['{key.content}']" for i, key in enumerate(input_keys) if
                key.type == 0),
            outputs=''.join(
                f"{key.get_type_display().lower()}{j + 1}['{key.content}']" for j, key in enumerate(output_keys) if
                key.type == 1))

        if valid_python_code(code):
            return eval(code)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid code or missing libs or whatever.')
```

Lemme comment here the problems I tackled when implementing this.

- `RuleKey.TYPES` is an `IntegerChoices` class, Django takes the attributes and capitalizes the first letter and returns it, Your code needs `input` and not `Input` , fortunately we have `str.lower()`
- The second problem is that a regular for-in loop doesn't have a counter when looping objects other than `range` objects, We will use `enumerate` instead.
- The third problem is that f-strings introduced in Python-3.6 (Not sure of 3.6) don't support *GENEXPS* inside, You have to use `.format()`
- The fourth problem is that when using a *GENEXP* directly inside format instead of using `''.join(GENEXP)`, You'll print the lazy version of it i.e `<generator object at 0x214312>`
- Don't try to use `keys = keys.objects.all()` and do this in one query, The problem you'll face will be related to the foor loop counter
- Don't use RuleKey.type, this returns the integer, You need to call django's `get_foo_display` and in this case it's `get_type_display()`

#### Let's illustrate

I'll name my variables on the following format, class_type_content

```
keys = [key_1_poor, key_0_good, key_1_average]
```

let's loop and filter

```
for key in keys: # no count  
    pass
```

let's enumerate

```
for i, item in enumerate(keys):
    print(i) # prints index
    print(item) # prints object
```

now for the `.all()` part, If you tried to iterate `.all()`, You'll succeed, however, If your input started with `input1`, Your output will start with `output2` and this is because both are in the same `Queryset` object.

Now, Add this to your `admin` page, perhaps as a button.

```
# admin.py

class RuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_change(self, request, rule_obj):
        if "execute" in request.POST:
            try:
                obj.execute() # execute (DONT IGNORE THE NOTES BELOW)
                obj.wasExecutedBefore = True 
                obj.save()
            except (ValueError, TypeError): # eval failed or execute
                pass

            return redirect(".")
        return super().response_change(request, obj)


admin.site.register(Rule, RuleAdmin) # register with admin
```

**NOTE** You need to import `re` and all the required libs like `scikit` and the ones needed for your code in your `models.py`.

Now in your app, I named my app `core` , create `templates/admin/core/rule`, this is on the following format. `<app_name/templates/admin/app_name/model_name>` all lowercase.

add a file called `change_form.html`

add this

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <div class="submit-row">
            <input type="submit" value="Execute the rule" name="execute">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

This creates a form that posts `execute` then we capture it in the model admin and if it exists, we execute the code.

I've written [this dev.to article](https://dev.to/leondaz/how-to-execute-code-from-admin-page-in-django-229b) based on this topic